# Forward Unassigned Values in Cube

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, cube, dimension

i have build a Cube in the following way:
A Measure Table

```
fact_Prdoduction
----------------
ProductionCost
CustomerID
PlaningValue
```

and a Dimension:

```
Dim_Customer
------------
CustomerID
CustomerName
```

Now the Problem I am having is that there are values in fact_Production (where PlaningValue is = true)
where all of the CustomerID Values are NULL.
While processing the Cube i got Errors because it wasn't able to assignt Customers to those ProductionCost Values,so i entered the Dim_Customer Dimension and changed the ErrorConfiguration Properties to **ReportandContinue**,
 and now I'm left with a Cube who only has part of the Values and not all.
Is there a way around it, i mean something as in **fact_Production Left Join Dim_Customer**, which would take all values and simply Forward the NULL Values as unassigned Values ?
A lot of thanks to you all in advance!

Comment: Could you create an unknown/unassigned customer in Dim_Customer? Then all rows will tie back from the fact table.  This is fairly common in data warehousing.

Answer (score 0):

i found the Answer,
in my case it was a Dimension which was being connected to the fact_Production table through another Dimension and was set to Materialize, all i did was Switch it off,

before that i entered the Dimensions and changed the Properties of what they do in Case of Null Keys